# Function in same package undefined

Tags: go

My project structure is like this.

```
packagetest/
    main.go
    lib.go
```

In `main.go`, I have this code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from main.go.")
    Test()
}
```

While in `lib.go`, I have this code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("This is the Test function in lib.go.")
}
```

When I try to compile with `go build main.go`, I get `./main.go:7: undefined: Test`. Is this way of structuring my code possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I "go run" a project with multiple files in the main package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081486/how-can-i-go-run-a-project-with-multiple-files-in-the-main-package)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try running just `go build`. When you give it a go file as an argument, it will not look for other go files. You can also do `go build *.go`

Comment: for those who might have the same issue as me: note that the definitions in `main_test.go` won't be visible to `main.go`. (But why would you try to access them right?)

Answer (score 26):

This is an old post but it didn't answer my issue clearly, so I'm posting for the benefit of others in the future.

When run `go run --help` you will find this manual:

> Run compiles and runs the main package comprising the named Go source files.
>   A Go source file is defined to be a file ending in a literal ".go" suffix.
>
> By default, 'go run' runs the compiled binary directly: 'a.out arguments...'.

`go run <filename.go>` is used for small programs with just a few files. With several files you will run into an issue where your `main.go` cannot find other files because `go run` doesn't compile and link them implicitly unless named. That's why `go build` the project works.

Alternatively, `go run *.go` (building all files) should work most of the time.

Comment: When I ran : `go run *.go`, It says: `CreateFile *.go: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` (go version go1.10 windows/amd64, Windows 10 x64)

Answer (score 9):

On the [golang.org](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) webpage you can read about the `build` command that:

> If the arguments are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.

So, `go build main.go` will treat main.go as a single package. Instead, you should use:

```
go build
```

to include all files in the folder.

Answer (score 9):

You can also try below command if you don't want to `build` but simply execute it :

```
go run main.go lib.go
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem will happen when go cannot find your other file (like `lib.go` in this example).

**If you use JetBrains Goland , you should change your "Run kind" to "Directory"**.  Goland  will help you to do these:

- `go build .`
- run this execution file.

---

If you use JetBrains Goland , you can contrast the difference between "Run kind".[image]

When i select "File", and then run, you will see the message on the console, like this:

```
GOROOT=C:\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\hgs\go #gosetup
C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\hgs\AppData\Local\Temp\___go_build_select_go__4_.exe "C:/Users/hgs/Google Drive/My Maps/computer/2.programming_lang/Golang/source-code-refer/basic/select.go" #gosetup
# command-line-arguments
.\select.go:14:16: undefined: Add
```

When you select "Directory" and select your directory, and then run, you will see something like this:

```
GOROOT=C:\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\hgs\go #gosetup
C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\hgs\AppData\Local\Temp\___go_build_basic_.exe . #gosetup
C:\Users\hgs\AppData\Local\Temp\___go_build_basic_.exe #gosetup
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Run all the file then able to call

```
go run *.go
```

or

```
go run main.go lib.go
```

Answer (score 3):

If using multiple files for Go main pkg, instead of single file path as go run main.go, go require main pkg dir in the run or build command, like:

```
#from outside packagetest dir
go run ./packagetest/
go build ./packagetest/

#from within packagetest:
go run ./
go build ./
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you can only have one file using package main.

Try putting lib.go in a different package.  This requires:

1. lib.go to exist in a folder with the same name as the new package (*e.g.*, myLibs).
2. Adding the package name to lib.go (package myLibs).

Then, in main:

```
import myLibs
call myLibs.Test()
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who may need this.

I had a similar issue. However, my problem was that the function I wanted to call was in a `my_test.go` file, and I was trying to call it from a file that was not called `*_test.go` but `testutils.go`. (Maybe someone will tell me not to have a `testutils.go` file?)