# How can I "go run" a project with multiple files in the main package?

Tags: go, package

I have a single file in the `main` package called `main.go`. Because the code isn't reusable I want to separate part of the code in a different file but in the same package.

How do I split the contents of `main.go` into multiple files without creating a separate package?

I want a directory structure like this:

```bash
ls foo

# output:
main.go
bar.go
```

#### File `bar.go`

```golang
// file bar.go
package main

import "fmt"

func Bar() {
  fmt.Println("Bar")
}
```

#### File `main.go`

```golang
// file main.go
package main

func main() {
  Bar()
}
```

In `main.go` i want to use `func Bar()` from `bar.go`. But when I run `go run main.go` it results in:

```bash
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:4:2: undefined: Bar
```

What can be done do run the code without an error?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

### Update 26th July 2019 (for go >=1.11)

```sh
go run .
```

Will work on windows as well.

### Original answer (for non windows environments)

The code actually works. The problem was that instead of running `go run main.go` I should run:

```sh
go run *.go
```

Comment: Unless you have `*_test.go` in your folder. Then you need to (1) `shopt -s ext glob` and (2) `go run !(*_test).go`.

Comment: and what about those using appengine?

Comment: I tried `go run ./cmd/myCmd/...` and it worked for me. Maybe this is the correct way when there are `_test.go` files?

Comment: ```go run ../your_folder``` from inside the working folder works for me

Comment: Just do `go run .`

Comment: You might need to add the `./` prefix. For example `go run ./cmd`

Answer (score 76):

Update August 2018, with [Go 1.11](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11), a [section "Run"](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#run) states:

> The [`go run`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) command now allows a single import path, a directory name or a pattern matching a single package.
>   This allows `go run pkg` or `go run dir`, most importantly `go run .`

---

Original answer Jan. 2015

As mentioned in "[How to compile Go program consisting of multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872133/6309)", [`go run`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) expects a list of files, since it "compiles and runs the `main` package comprising the named Go source files".
So you certainly can split your `main` package in several files with `go run`.

That differs from [`go build/go install`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) which expect package names (and not go filenames).
A simple `go build` would produce an executable named after the parent folder.

Note that, as [illustrated by this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/go-language-discuss/2013-01/msg03653.html), a `go run *.go` wouldn't work in a Windows CMD session, since the [shell doesn't do wildcard expansion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2005/05/14/417547.aspx).

Comment: Is there a workaround for running multiple go files with `run` using the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a ton. I kept wondering why I couldn't just run the code with just main.go since it was the same package but it kind of makes sense to me as to why they didn't allow for that.

Comment: @Luke just specify both files separated by a space.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, the best answer to this question is hidden in the comments to the top answer.

Just run this:

```
go run .
```

This will run all the files in main package, but will **not** give an error message like

```
go run: cannot run *_test.go files (main_test.go)
```

Kudos to @BarthesSimpson

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, you can say `go run *.go` but for Windows you can just list the script files (since *.go won't work) - `go run main.go other.go third.go`

Comment: Yes thats correct. In windows i had to run `go run .`

Answer (score 3):

The first method to do so will be to run

```
go run *.go
```

The another method is to generate an exe file

```
go build
```

Then run that .exe file

```
./filename.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

With current-day Golang, `go run .` isn't sufficient by itself.

First, you need to initialize the folder with a one-time setup:

```
go mod init noname
```

Now you can run your program with:

```
go run .
```

---

Although it doesn't explain the significance of the name chosen for use with `go mod init`, this method is demonstrated here: [Tutorial: Get started with Go](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started). A key point is that "Enable dependency tracking for your code" is optional for the most trivial cases like a typical `go run .`, but is essentially required for any non-trivial applications or workflows (for example using non-standard imports).

The use of `noname` in the above example can be replaced by anything that looks like a relative path-name. It basically doesn't matter what you use as the module name if you're building a main module that you don't plan to import elsewhere.

A basic explanation of `go mod init` was previously asked for here: [Can someone please dumb down go mod init for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67606062/86967)

---

Note: Without `go mod init (somename)`, `go run .` returns an error like so...

```
$ go run .
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

There may be alternative solutions: [Error message "go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66894200)

Comment: Note, though, that `go build .` uses the module name as the binary name -- so in that case, it matters what you choose.

Comment: As noted in the output of `go mod init (name)`, you typically follow this with `go mod tidy` if your module has external dependencies.

Comment: There seam to be _reasons_ that you want to match the name of your folder with the name of the module.

Comment: *"install _or_ import elsewhere".

Answer (score 1):

For Windows install Cygwin and use it instead of command prompt. "go run *.go" will work then.

Comment: I would suggest MinGW for that, but the approach is right if you ask me. I doubt that anyone could be really emotionally attached to `cmd.exe`

Comment: I'm using go 1.20,  I can "go run ." in Windows  and "go run *.go" in Cygwin (which is installed on Windows), but can't  "go run *.go" in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options

1. `go run .`
2. `go run *.go`
3. `make run` using `Makefile` where, add any of the above command as build target.

for testing

1. `go test ./...`
2. `make test` using `Makefile` with `go test ./...` as build target

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run multiple files on localhost using gorilla mux in go as per latest version(1.11). Try using any of the following 2 commands.

> 1. go install && FolderName  -port 8081 .
> 2. go build && ./FolderName  -port 8081.

Make sure that you are in the source folder ie go/src/FolderName before executing the command in the Terminal.