# Can you have more than one Go source file in a single directory?

Tags: go

[I found this to be a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081486/golang-multiple-files-in-main-package).

---

---

---

**Hello World**

Just started learning golang and tried to figure out how to structure a larger program. Not sure if packages are the split I want or if there is something else more suitable for having multiple source files in a single directory, but here's what I tried.

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Testing running it:

```
~/b2/go/src/github.com/bemmu/hello bemmu$ go run hello.go
hello, world
```

**Two file version**

I wanted to try splitting it into two files.

*main.go*

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "say"

func main() {
    say.Hello()
}
```

*say.go*

```
package say
import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, Go\n")
}
```

Testing running it:

```
~/b2/go/src/github.com/bemmu/hello_split bemmu$ go run main.go
main.go:4:8: cannot find package "say" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/say (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/bemmu/b2/go/src/say (from $GOPATH)
```

In [the docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) there is an example of creating a library and importing it, but in the example case it is put into a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

No, Just create a new directory for another package.