# Is it wrong duplicate "func main" in "package main" and why it is wrong?

Tags: go, build, package, program-entry-point, golang-migrate

Please help me to understand why duplicate "func main" in "package main" is wrong. Error in VC: "main redeclared in this block".

````golang
// $ tree
// .
// ├── main.go
// ├── second.go

// ```go build main.go```
// or 
// ```go build .```


// file: main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("this is file MAIN")
}

// file: second.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("this is file SECOND")
}
````

I can build/run this:
go build/run main.go - correct
go build/run . - wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I "go run" a project with multiple files in the main package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081486/how-can-i-go-run-a-project-with-multiple-files-in-the-main-package)

Answer (score 7):

You can't have the same symbol declared twice at the package level in the same package.

And if you have 2 files in the same folder, both having `package main` declaration, that is exactly what you're doing. This is why your IDE complains: it tries to build / compile those 2 files as one package, same as writing `go build .`: this designates the package in the current folder, including all source files.

`go run main.go` and `go run second.go` works because you specify *files* to build (more specifically a single file), not packages. And having a single `main.go` or `second.go` being the `main` package does not violate the above rule: each file only contains the `main()` function once.

So in short: `go run main.go` **ignores** `second.go`.

Usually if you want to create multiple apps with multiple `main()` functions in the same project, it's easiest to just place different `main()` functions in different folders, conventionally inside a `cmd` folder.

[See Command Go:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

> ### [Compile packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Build compiles the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> **If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.**
>
> ### [Compile and run Go program](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] package [arguments...]
> ```
>
> Run compiles and runs the named main Go package. **Typically the package is specified as a list of .go source files, but it may also be an import path, file system path, or pattern matching a single known package, as in 'go run .' or 'go run my/cmd'.**

Also see [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can not find documentation about this case.
A phrase like this: you can use both possibilities, but it is recommended ...

Answer (score 0):

In Go,a directory is a package, and a package can only have **one func** with a given name(exception of a special case that is **init()**)
Think of all your .go files in a directory as separate, but Go does not, it sees as a single package and that package declares multiple functions called main, which is not permitted.

Separating them(the main() func) into their own directories is the solution.