# Go: undefined function in same package

Tags: go

I've started Go and am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.activestate.com/blog/2017/04/creating-web-app-using-golang-gorilla-web-toolkit). Everything builds correct but as I try to run it, I get the error that `makeRouter()` could not be found.

I had a look at some other questions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171409/function-in-same-package-undefined), and checked the docs, but I couldn't find out whats wrong with my setup.

#### My folder structure:

```
.../wattagebazooka/
  |- wattagebazooka.go
  |- router.go
  |- handler.go
```

#### Code

wattagebazooka.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

// init sets runtime settings.
func init() {
    // Verbose logging with file name and line number
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

    // Use all CPU cores
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
}

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    db = openDB()
    defer db.Close()

    r := makeRouter()
    http.Handle("/", r)
}

func openDB() *sql.DB {
    dbName := "wattagebazooka"

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("user=ts password= dbname=%s host=127.0.0.1", dbName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error connecting to the %s database as user ts: %v", dbName, err)
    }

    return db
}
```

router.go

```
package main

import "github.com/gorilla/mux"

func makeRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/user/me", wrapHandler(userHandler)).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/text", wrapHandler(textHandler)).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/text/{hash}", wrapHandler(textHashHandler)).Methods("GET")
    return r
}
```

#### Build

```
> Environment:
>   GOROOT=/usr/local/go
>   GOPATH=/Users/ts/Developments/gocode
> Directory: /Users/ts/Developments/gocode/src/github.com/wattagebazooka/wattagebazooka
> Command: /usr/local/go/bin/go build -v
> Output:
github.com/wattagebazooka/wattagebazooka
> Elapsed: 0.708s
> Result: Success
```

#### Run

```
> Environment:
>   GOROOT=/usr/local/go
>   GOPATH=/Users/ts/Developments/gocode
> Directory: /Users/ts/Developments/gocode/src/github.com/wattagebazooka/wattagebazooka
> Command: /usr/local/go/bin/go run -v /Users/ts/Developments/gocode/src/github.com/wattagebazooka/wattagebazooka/wattagebazooka.go
> Output:
command-line-arguments
# command-line-arguments
./wattagebazooka.go:28:7: undefined: makeRouter
> Elapsed: 0.244s
> Result: Error
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run your program via `go run` you need to add all source files to the command.

In your case, you only have `wattagebazooka.go` but are missing `router.go` and `handler.go`.