# local Method call results in: undeclared name: [name]

Tags: go

### Summary: Local Method call (inside same file) results in: `[govet] undeclared name: QueryPart [Error]`

### Edit: Please see summary of mistakes and correction at bottom of post.

I'm very new to Go, and am trying to build some simple Hyperledger Fabric chaincode.

In the following code, I have a method `QueryPart` which I can call successfully.  I wanted to see if I could write another method `QueryPartSpecial` to call the original `QueryPart` method (and then do some other stuff), but I'm getting a fatal error: `[govet] undeclared name: QueryPart [Error]`

```
  231 //QueryPart: queries a single part from the ledger (with provided partID)
  232 func (s *SmartContract) QueryPart(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, partID string) (*Part, error) {
  233   assetJSON, err := ctx.GetStub().GetState(partID)
  234   if err != nil {
  235     return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read from world state: %v", err)
  236   }
  237   if assetJSON == nil {
  238     return nil, fmt.Errorf("the asset %s does not exist", partID)
  239   }
  240   
  241   var part Part
  242   err = json.Unmarshal(assetJSON, &part)
  243   if err != nil {
  244     return nil, err
  245   }
  246 
  247   return &part, nil
  248 }
  249 
  250 //QueryPartSpecial: calls QueryPart and does some other experimental stuff on it
  251 func QueryPartSpecial(partID string) (*Part, error) {
✘ 252   part, err := QueryPart(partID)
  253   //placeholder for some other code
  254   return part, err
  255 }
```

Why would I get this error since func `QueryPart` is clearly declared above?

Note: This question appears very similar to the following questions:
[Function in same package undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171409/function-in-same-package-undefined)
[Go: undefined function in same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645061/go-undefined-function-in-same-package)

However, the main difference from these other questions is that my two functions reside inside in the same [file].go.

Note 2: the error I am getting is a linting error, but is also preventing me from compiling/installing the chaincode.

### Edit: What I did wrong and what I learned:

The error I received was due to problems with the `QueryPartSpecial` method, rather than the `QueryPart` method.

As a new learner to Go, I made several mistakes:

1. Confusing [methods and functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/methods-in-golang/).
   (In my original post, I referred to both methods as functions.)
2. Incorrectly constructing `QueryPartSpecial`: As Lucas pointed out, I did not include any object in `QueryPartSpecial`.  By modifying this function to a method with a pointer receiver of SmartContract, I could provide an object when calling `QueryPart`.
3. Incorrectly calling the method `QueryPart`: Since methods operate on a object, they should be called on an object.

This is my corrected code (which is functional without an error returned):

```
255 //QueryPartSpecial: calls QueryPart and does some other experimental stuff on it
256 func (s *SmartContract) QueryPartSpecial(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, partID string) (*Part, error) {
257   part, err := s.QueryPart(ctx,partID)
258   //placeholder for some other code
259   return part, err
260 }
```

(Thank you, Lucas, Adrian, and Volker for your help and for steering me in the right direction.)

Comment: Please learn Go, e.g.  via tour.golang.org. QueryPart is a method and thus cannot be called without an opbject.

Comment: `QueryPart` is a method of `*SmartContract`, so it must be called on a `*SmartContract` instance. `QueryPartSpecial` is a plain function with no receiver.

Comment: @Volker What do you mean by an "object" in Golang?

Comment: Thank you Adrian and Volker for your feedback.  (I've been through the tour.golang already, but admittedly am still trying to learn.)  I understanding that QueryPart is a method (and not a function like I first stated).  However, I'm still confused as to why I get the mentioned error.  (Note that the error is not present if I remove lines 250-255.)

Comment: Object: An instance of a type. Learn the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [pointer receiver](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4) for the method `QueryPart`. From the docs:

> Methods with pointer receivers can modify the value to which the
> receiver points

So you will need to call the method on the object itself, something similar to this:

```
contract := SmartContract{}
contract.QueryPart(ctx)
```

Or to call it directly remove the receiver (convert to a function as commented above by Adrian):

```
func QueryPart(...) // (s *SmartContract) receiver removed
```